# Poisson process. Patients arriving te the ER.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

People arrive to the ER of a hospital following a poisson process with $\lambda=2.1$ patients/hour. One of each 28 who arrives under this condition, dies. Calculate the probability of:

(a) At least one of the patients that arrive today, dies.
(b) The maximum of patients that die today, is 4.

If I let $N(t)$ be the number of patients that arrive to the ER at time $t$ and I know that each patient dies with probability $\frac{1}{28}$, is the patient $k$ will be dead by time $t$ with probability $p(k)=\mathbb{P}[W_k\leq t]\frac{1}{28}$? Can I use this to define $X(t)$ (the number of patients dead) in terms of $N(t)$, or what will be the best way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found both answers really helpful. Thank you so much. However I chose the one that applied the splitting because it ends up using more about poisson processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above question can be solved in this way....
Split the poisson process into two different poission
1. $N_1(t)$-: Number of patient died with rate $\lambda*\frac{1}{28}$

2. $N_2(t)$-: Number of patient alive with rate $\lambda*\frac{27}{28}$

Now the question (a) and (b) can easily be solved using first poisson process.

Answer (score 0):

On average, there die 2.1/28=0.075 patients per hour, therefore 1.8 per day.

(a). 1-poissonpdf(1.8,0)

(b). poissoncdf(4,0)